# Bounding Kullback-Leibler

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, st.statistics, it.information-theory

Suppose we have a probability distribution $P$ on a finite set $S$.  We draw $N$ i.i.d. samples according to $P$ and use these samples to define an empirical distribution $R$.  We measure the Kullback-Leibler divergence between $P$ and $R$:
$$A_{P,N}:=D_{KL}(R||P)=\sum_{s\in S} R(s) \log\left(\frac{R(s)}{P(s)}\right)$$
(We are treating $A_{P,N}$ as a random variable.)

Question: Can someone provide an explicit upper bound on the probability of a righthand tail event?  I.e., I'm looking for some function $f_{P,N}(B)$ such that for any $B>0$,
$$\Pr(A_{P,N} > B) \leq f_{P,N}(B)$$

---

A few comments:

- Since $R$ is drawn from $P$, then $D_{KL}$ is a.s. finite, so $A_{P,N}$ is supported on $[0,\infty)$
- I'm curious about the asymptotics of the tail (e.g., does the probability decay like $e^{-B}$ or $e^{-B^2}$ or what?), but ultimately I need an explicit, computable bound.
- It seemed like [Sanov's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanov%27s_theorem) might be the correct tool, but I can't seem to figure out how to apply it.
- In a perfect world, we would prefer a function of $(|S|, N)$ instead of $(P, N)$, i.e., if only the number of elements, rather than the specific distribution, dictated the bound.

Finally, a few figures.  This is almost certainly of little help (since it only describes the bulk of the probability, not the tail), but for what it's worth, here's a plot of the CDF of $A_{P,N}$, with various values for $|S|$ and $N$ (normalized so such that mean=0, variance=1):

[image: CDF of normalized KL divergence]

and here's a detail from that figure:
[image]
(Each CDF line is drawn from 10,000 samples.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right that Sanov's theorem is relevant.
There are extensions to it as well, see for example [Concentration Inequalities for the Empirical Distribution](https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.06522).
The introduction of it states the following is a consequence (or more properly, used in the proof of) Sanov's theorem.

> Let $P$ be a discrete distribution with $k = |\mathsf{supp}(P)|$. Let $\hat{P}_{n}$ be the empirical distribution obtained from $n$ i.i.d. samples from $P$.
> Then
> $$\Pr[D_{KL}(\hat{P}_n||P) \geq \epsilon] \leq \binom{n+k-1}{k-1}\exp(-n\epsilon).$$

This bound is known to be asymptotically tight for fixed $\epsilon$, $k$, but it is known the bound is non-tight when $k$ varies with $n$.

One can obtain stronger results if one gives a tail-bound for $D_{KL}(\hat{P}_n||P)$ around its mean.

> **Corollary 1.2 of [Finite-sample concentration of the empirical relative entropy around its mean](https://arxiv.org/abs/2203.00800)**: Let $P$ be a discrete distribution with $k = |\mathsf{supp}(P)|$, and let $\hat{P}_n$ be the empirical distribution obtained from $n$ i.i.d. samples from $P$. Then
> $$\Pr[\left|D_{KL}(\hat{P}_n||P) - \mathbb{E}[D_{KL}(\hat{P}_n||P)]\right| \geq \epsilon] \leq 2 \exp\left(-\frac{\min\left(\frac{n^2\epsilon^2}{k-1}, n\epsilon\right)}{48}\right) $$

Comment: Thank you, Mark, that's perfect!